# How can I get total user in a group from database by PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in database:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRJFf.png]

How can I get total user for each group. i.e: group 1: total are 2 users;
group2: total are 2 users;
group3: total is 1 user

Comment: If you can you should change your CSV value col `user_group_id` to an extra table where you have two cols: `user_id`and `group_id`. You can then use foreign keys and easily to what you need with a simly `count(*)` query without doing string related stuff.

Comment: thanks for your solution but I can not change it. you know, I'm not a boss :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need normalization and never store comma-separated data.
Consider the following

```
mysql> select * from user_table ;
+---------+---------------+
| user_id | user_group_id |
+---------+---------------+
|       1 | 1,2           |
|       2 | 2             |
|       3 | 1,3           |
+---------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from group_table ;
+----------+------------+
| group_id | group_name |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | a          |
|        2 | b          |
|        3 | c          |
+----------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The above data is not normalized and to get the desired result out of these you need to use some in-efficient query as

```
select 
g.group_id,
count(*) as  total 
from group_table g 
left join user_table u on find_in_set(g.group_id,u.user_group_id) > 0 
group by g.group_id ;

+----------+-------+
| group_id | total |
+----------+-------+
|        1 |     2 |
|        2 |     2 |
|        3 |     1 |
+----------+-------+
```

Now lets do normalization and store user-group data in a different table as

```
mysql> select * from user_to_group ;
+---------+----------+
| user_id | group_id |
+---------+----------+
|       1 |        1 |
|       1 |        2 |
|       2 |        2 |
|       3 |        1 |
|       3 |        3 |
+---------+----------+
```

You can easily write different queries from these tables now and here are some examples

```
select group_id,count(*) as  tot from user_to_group group by group_id ;

+----------+-----+
| group_id | tot |
+----------+-----+
|        1 |   2 |
|        2 |   2 |
|        3 |   1 |
+----------+-----+
```

Joining the tables would even more easy

```
select 
g.group_id,
g.group_name,
count(*) as  tot 
from user_to_group ug 
join group_table g on g.group_id = ug.group_id 
join user_table u on u.user_id = ug.user_id 
group by g.group_id

+----------+------------+-----+
| group_id | group_name | tot |
+----------+------------+-----+
|        1 | a          |   2 |
|        2 | b          |   2 |
|        3 | c          |   1 |
+----------+------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT group_name, COUNT(*) FROM user_table u, group_table g WHERE u.user_group_id LIKE %g.group_id% GROUP BY g.group_name;
```

this should work and give you a list of all groups and how many users are in them.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will get you wrong results, when e.g. there are groups with ID `1` and `11` because if you search after `like %1%` it will give back two results for 1 and 11. You understand what I mean?

Comment: @bish 56 indeed that would cause problems. But with the way hey design hsi table it can't be changes.
For a better table setup Abhik Chakraborty provided a good answer.

Comment: i don't think that is a good id. example for when I have 2 more: group id=10 and 11. 
that's mean user_group_id like %1% you can not search it on user have id=1, 10 or 11

Comment: @yanndinh than you should read the other answers and think about changing your db-structure. With the field user_group_id the way you have it you can't get a better solution.

Comment: thankyou @DocRattie, I want to change it too. But i can't, because my boss degree with a change. so I must find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your specific question but rather an alternative data structure proposal that might be better.

Introduce a new table `members` that looks like

```
# members
user_id  |  group_id
   1     |     1
   1     |     2
   2     |     2
   3     |     1
   3     |     3
```

Then you could `SELECT group_id, count(*) FROM members GROUP BY group_id`

```
+----------+----------+
| group_id | count(*) |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |        2 |
|        2 |        2 |
|        3 |        1 |
+----------+----------+
```

This structure might also make it easier for you to manage your memberships. user_id + group_id should be unique. And if supported let them be foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to create a third table which holds the information about which users are in which groups.

```
CREATE TABLE users_in_groups 
(
   user_id INT
 , group_id INT
);
```

Then you can join like this:

```
SELECT 
   gt.group_id
 , count(ut.user_id)
FROM
   user_table AS ut
 , INNER JOIN users_in_groups AS uig ON uig.user_id = ut.user_id
 , INNER JOIN group_table AS gt ON gt.group_id = uig.group_id
GROUP BY
   gt.group_id
;
```

To use the table you have now will you have to do something like this (in mysql):

```
SELECT
       gt.group_id
     , count(ut.user_id)
FROM
   user_table AS ut
 , INNER JOIN group_table AS gt ON LOCATE(gt.group_id, ut.user_group_id) > 0
GROUP BY
   gt.group_id
```

Remember, when using group by, always locate what makes your group unique!